# how to make a bot that connects to a conference?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

How to make the graph api bot wait for the conference to appear in a certain channel and then connect, and if the conference did not appear at that time, did something else?

Comment: You should get [started by register calls and meetings bot Microsoft teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot) and see if it suits your scneario.